# Add field on registration form for specific website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a custom module that add a field to the registration form and account modification.

The problem is that it is added to all websites. I only need it on a specific website.

This is the module I created:

https://github.com/stfn97/magento2-custom-registration-field

Comment: You can create a field "not required" and show/hide according to the website in the registration page.

Answer (score 0):

> Custom customer attributes scope is global.